# How to make an HTTP response 'private' with Plone

Tags: plone

I have reported a bug at https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12345 because the view @@toggle-visibility is cached by varnish, so you can't change the visibility of a portlet once you have hide it.

I have a workaround where I add the date as param of the request but I guess the best solution is to make the HTTP response private. So the question is what is the best way to achieve this.

I know p.app.caching change response header to play well with varnish, but I don't know if I add a header to make the response private is plone.app.caching will change it ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless explicitely configured to do so, plone.app.caching will not overwrite cache control headers for arbitrary views.

In other words, unless you create a cache rule for the `@@toggle-visibility` view to tell plone.app.caching to do otherwise, the Cache-Control header set by that view will be left untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Where there are not caching headers, Varnish will use the default ttl. We should just set the appropriate caching headers for the redirect. I fixed this in PAS recently:  http://zope3.pov.lt/trac/changeset/121831/Products.PluggableAuthService/trunk